# Possible Bug? Measure returns different results on PBI Desktop and Service?

Tags: powerbi, dax

This measure:

```
ValorLíquidoProduto = 
SUMX (
    FILTER ( 'order_product'; 'order_product'[EstadoEncomenda] = "confirmed" );
    (
        (
            order_product[order_product_price]
                * ( 1 - RELATED ( nomes_produtos[comissao_perc] ) )
                - RELATED ( nomes_produtos[comissao_fixo] )
        )
            / order_product[Câmbio AOA]
            - order_product[DescontoProporcional]
    )
        * 'order_product'[order_product_quantity]
)
```

Returns €75 for order id 1940 as you can see below in Power BI Desktop (which is correct):

[image]

And it returns €149 for the same order in Power BI Service:

[image]

Why? It is the same model!

Is this a bug? Can anyone help?

Here is the relationship between the 2 tables in the data model:

[image]

Comment: Are you positive they are working on exactly the same set and version of the data and relationships? Have you tried re-uploading the PBIX to the service?

Comment: I sure did, I've re-published and changed some visuals to be sure. It is the same model.

Comment: Can you share the file? If not, can you create a minimal example that reproduces the issue? This is definitely strange behavior.

Comment: I'll try to create an example

Comment: I've found out what the problem is: field [comissao_perc] was not converted into decimal number. So, in PBI Desktop, somehow the calculation is good, but in PBI Service it isn't (it seems this value is just ignored). So, there is a difference in treatment of values between Service and Desktop